# Map one mongodb field to two POJO properties

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I have a property on my mongodb entity, lets call it `foo`.

When I retrieve this property, i want its value to be set on two different properties of my POJO, `foo` and `bar`

So if a document is registered as:

```
{
  "_id": "xxxxxx",
  "foo": "123",
}
```

When the service retrieves it from the DB, i want the fetched entity to look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "xxxxxx",
  "foo": "123",
  "bar": "123",
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this only changing the entity class? I tried the following and it didn't work

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document("test")
public class MyClass {
    @Id
    private String _id;

    @BsonProperty("foo")
    private String bar;

    private String foo;

}
```

I'm using Spring Webflux and Reactive MongoDB stack.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not allowed to map multiple properties to a single db field but you can redefine getter for` bar` `public String getBar() { return foo; }`

Comment: @Alex good catch, i'll try it later and come back here if it works on my use-case :)

Comment: @Alex please post your comment as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not allowed to map multiple object fields to a single db field but you can redefine getter for the `bar`

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document("test")
public class MyClass {
    @Id
    private String _id;

    @BsonProperty("foo")
    private String foo;

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() { 
       return foo; 
    }

}
```